# OpenWhisk open source UI?

Tags: openwhisk

Is there any opensource Web UI project for OpenWhisk?

I would like use OpenWhisk but not with IBM Bluemix‎.

Thanks.

Comment: UI for what tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple implementation I was able to find on GitHub, however haven't tested them:

https://github.com/katarzyna-dusza/openwhisk-react-ui

https://github.com/surawhisk/ui

Comment: Thanks i will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [IBM Cloud Functions Shell](https://github.com/ibm-functions/shell) which combines a command-line interface and a graphical user interface for OpenWhisk. This works with both IBM Bluemix and any OpenWhisk deployment.

Comment: Thanks but i would like a real web ui like in IBM bluemix :-)